# Force theme or disallow theme change

Tags: themes

Can I force a theme? I mean that the user cannot change intentionaly or accidentaly the theme I made for that website.
I would like to do this from the core because I also want to lock all updates.

Comment: What has been your research so far? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. More info about how to ask a good question can be found on the [ask] page.

Comment: There is bit of a fork here - while you technically asking how to prevent theme change, the more appropriate would indeed be to prevent users from having permission to make that change. Please clarify which route you are interested in.

Comment: Yes. Simply remove access to the theme page for specific user roles would be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Lot of useless comments on this post from what seems like a pretty simple question.

change below `$theme_directory_name = 'twentyfourteen';` to your theme... thats all you have to do. First function sets your theme no matter what. Second one disables interface to edit themes.

```
function selfish_hardcoded_theme() {
    $theme_directory_name = 'twentyfourteen';
    add_filter( 'template', create_function( '$template', 'return "' . $theme_directory_name . '";' ) );
    add_filter( 'stylesheet', create_function( '$stylesheet', 'return "' . $theme_directory_name . '";' ) );
}
add_action( 'setup_theme', 'selfish_hardcoded_theme', -1 );


add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', function( $required_caps, $cap ) {
    if ( 'edit_themes' == $cap || 'switch_themes' == $cap || 'install_themes' == $cap || 'delete_themes' == $cap || 'update_themes' == $cap ) {
        $required_caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
    }
    return $required_caps;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Theres other ways too :

```
$theme = wp_get_theme(); 
if ('twentyfourteen' !== $theme->name || 'twentyfourteen' !== $theme->parent_theme) { 
    switch_theme( 'twentyfourteen' );
}
```

You can also set the default theme constant in your wp-config.

Lastly, remove themes menu from admin:

```
function remove_themes_submenus() {
  global $submenu;
  unset($submenu['themes.php'][5]); // Removes 'Themes'
  unset($submenu['themes.php'][15]); // Removes Theme Installer tab
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_themes_submenus');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom admin role and remove these standard admin capabilities:

```
function remove_admin_capabilities() {

    $admin = get_role( 'administrator' );

     $caps = array(
        'install_themes',
        'update_themes',
        'delete_themes',
        'edit_themes',
        'switch_themes',
        'edit_theme_options',
    );

    foreach ( $caps as $cap ) {

        $admin->remove_cap( $cap );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_admin_capabilities' );
```

Or simply force them to use the Editor role.